# Transform dictionary to list of items

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c': [7,8,9], 'd': [10,11,12]}
```

but I need it in this format:

```
[{'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':7, 'd':10},
 {'a':2, 'b':5, 'c':8, 'd':11),
 {'a':3, 'b':6, 'c':9, 'd':12},
 ]
```

How could this be done (probably using list comprehension)?

What I had so far (but is not working):

```
[{k:v[i] for k,v in x.items()}
  for i in x 
]
```

Comment: Please update the question to show what you’ve tried already and why it’s not working.

Comment: Are you sure that there is always same number of items in the list for each key?

Answer (score 4):

One way using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

k = d.keys()
[dict(zip(k, i)) for i in zip(*itemgetter(*k)(d))]
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 7, 'd': 10},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 8, 'd': 11},
 {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 9, 'd': 12}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[{k: v[i] for k, v in original_dict.items()} for i in range(len(next(iter(original_dict.values()))))]
```

^That obviously only works if you know all the lists will be of the same length.

If you know the length of the lists in advance, you can simplify it:

```
[{k: v[i] for k, v in original_dict.items()} for i in range(3)]
```

If you don't know the length of the lists in advance, and you also can't be certain that all lists will be of the same length,  you can do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for k, v in original_dict.items():
    for i, sub_value in enumerate(v):
        new_dict[i][k] = sub_value

results = list(new_dict.values())
```

This last one you could also do with plain old `dict.setdefault()`, but using `collections.defaultdict` will [likely be faster](https://realpython.com/python-defaultdict/#defaultdict-vs-dictsetdefault).

Comment: This returns a list index out of range

Comment: @Haha yup, stupid mistake on my part — have corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

A rather simple comprehension would be:

```
d = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c': [7,8,9], 'd': [10,11,12]}

[{k: d[k][i] for k in d} for i in range(next(map(len, d.values())))]
# [{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 7, 'd': 10}, 
#  {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 8, 'd': 11}, 
#  {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 9, 'd': 12}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses two list comprehensions:

```py
[{k: v[i] for k, v in d.items()} for i in range(len(d[list(d.keys())[0]]))]
```

Output:

```
[
    {"a": 1, "b": 4, "c": 7, "d": 10},
    {"a": 2, "b": 5, "c": 8, "d": 11},
    {"a": 3, "b": 6, "c": 9, "d": 12},
]
```

Comment: that seems to be something else

Comment: sorry, its fixed now